# Checking for duplicates in an ArrayList with a Comparator

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I want to implement a method, that removes duplicates from an ArrayList, by creating a new one without them. I already asked a question about the time complexity of this algorithm, but apparently it doesn't even work. I am pretty sure the error is the equality check but I am not very familiar with Comparators and ArrayLists so any help is appreciated. Here's the code:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> noDups(Comparator<T> cmp, ArrayList<T> l) {

    ArrayList<T> noDups = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(T o : l) {
        if(!isAlreadyInArrayList2(cmp, o, l)) 
            noDups.add(o);
    }
    return noDups;
}
```

With iterator:

```
public static <T> boolean isAlreadyInArrayList(Comparator<T> cmp, T o, ArrayList<T> l) {

Iterator<T> i = l.iterator();
    if (o==null) {
        while (i.hasNext())
            if (i.next()==null)
                 return true;
    } else {
        while (i.hasNext())
            if (cmp.compare(o, i.next()) == 0)
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

With a for loop:

```
public static <T> boolean isAlreadyInArrayList2(Comparator<T> cmp, T o, ArrayList<T> l) {

for(T obj : l) {
        if (cmp.compare(o, obj) == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is my test which produces an empty ArrayList:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Comparator<Integer> natural = Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder();
    ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 5, 4, 2, 2, 0, 1, 4, 2));
    System.out.println(test);
    ArrayList<Integer> testWithoutDuplicates = noDups(natural,test);
    System.out.println(testWithoutDuplicates);
}
```

Comment: What's the wrong output? Which version of the code are you actually trying to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the wrong List to your isAlreadyInArrayList2, change it to the following:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> noDups(Comparator<T> cmp, ArrayList<T> l) {

    ArrayList<T> noDups = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T o : l) {
        if (!isAlreadyInArrayList2(cmp, o, noDups))
            noDups.add(o);
    }
    return noDups;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't expect that the error would be there and didn't even look there.